# Passing html into a directive template using ng-bind-html-unsafe

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angular-strap for some tabs and need to change the directive to add some buttons to the last tab. I am trying to use ng-bind-html-unsafe to pass the html from a scope variable to the directive. This works up to a point.

What is not working is the calling of the function when I click the button generated by the code.

Here's the Plunk...

http://plnkr.co/edit/yDwbnQvSuu8fAFlXevhZ?p=preview